# Problema ao tentar adicionar elementos ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

Tenho uma pagina que carrega um modal bootstrap. 
Dentro do Modal existe uma textarea com ckeditor.
O problema quando eu tento adicionar uma tabela por exemplo, eu clico no icone de add tabela ele abre a janela de dialogo, mas nao consigo clicar nos inputs somente nos selects

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editarDocumento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">    

                <div class="form-group font-poppins">
                    <textarea id="editor1" class="form-control ckeditorActive"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <div class="spinner-border text-danger" role="status">
                            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <div class="btn-modal">
                    <a href="#" id="" class="btn btn-primary saveAnexo">Salvar</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>                 
                </div>               
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui eu chamo o ckeditor

```
    <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        uiColor: '#FDFDFD',
        removePlugins: 'resize',
        contentsCss: ['body {width: auto; height: auto;  padding: 0; font-family: "calibri";}'],
        toolbar: [{
                name: 'clipboard',
                items: ['PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']
            },
            {
                name: 'basicstyles',
                items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'RemoveFormat', 'Subscript', 'Superscript']
            },
            {
                name: 'links',
                items: ['Link', 'Unlink']
            },
            {
                name: 'paragraph',
                items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote']
            },
            {
                name: 'insert',
                items: ['Image', 'Table']
            },
            {
                name: 'editing',
                items: ['Scayt']
            },
            '/',

            {
                name: 'styles',
                items: ['Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']
            },
            {
                name: 'colors',
                items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor', 'CopyFormatting']
            },
            {
                name: 'align',
                items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']
            },
            {
                name: 'document',
                items: ['Print', 'PageBreak', 'Source']
            }
        ],

    });
</script>
```

[image: de acordo com a imagem aí, nao consigo clicar nos inputs para editar, somente nos selects, o que pode ser?]

de acordo com a imagem aí, nao consigo clicar nos inputs para editar, somente nos selects, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Já tive um problema parecido e acredito que irá servir para você também.

Isso pode acontecer quando a caixa de diálogo do CKEditor é acionada dentro de um modal ativo.

### Solução

Dentro da pasta do seu plugin, na raiz, existe um arquivo chamado `styles.js`, dentro desse arquivo vá ao final dele e adicione esse trecho de código ao final do arquivo.

> É possível também adicionar esse trecho entre as tags `scripts` dentro da sua página caso o problema seja apenas nessa página específica.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
        modal_this = this
        $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
            if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
                && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
                && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')
            ) {
                modal_this.$element.focus()
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Após salvar o arquivo, volte à sua página, atualize ela e tente criar novamente uma tabela em seu editor.

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema também com o ckeditor abrindo no modal usando Bootstrap 4. Eu só achava solução pra resolver para boostrap 3. Após muito pesquisar encontrei a solução. Segue abaixo:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function _enforceFocus() {
    var _this4 = this;
    $(document).on(Event.FOCUSIN, function (event) {
        if (
            document !== event.target
            && _this4._element !== event.target
            && $(_this4._element).has(event.target).length === 0
            && !$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select')
            && !$(event.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')
        ) {
            _this4._element.focus();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço as respostas, ontem de madrugada acabei resolvendo e é muito mais simples do que eu pensava, como sempre se tratando de programação.

Eu tentei esses scripts porém sem sucesso pra mim.

> o que fiz foi simplesmente remover o atributo **tabindex="-1"** do modal e tudo
>   funcionou normalmente.